# Make the navbar pop from top-bottom instead of bottom-top

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im creating a navbar with sticky. The idea is that the navbar goes invisible when the user scrolls down until they scroll up or when they reach the end of the website. I've written a JScript to achieve this and it is working fine. The problem I'm facing is, when the navbar becomes visible again, its popping few inches below the top and then transitioning up.This is because, the initial position of navbar is set at `top:6.3%` due to presence of other divs.The transition looks very odd. So instead what I'm trying to achieve is to make it pop in the top and move down. I've tried adding different animations in the CSS for this but it doesn't do the work. Will help if anyone can suggest how to do this. I'm attaching part of my code for reference.

```js
function isInViewport(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;


function scrollDetect() {
  var lastScroll = 0;
  window.onscroll = function() {
    let currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop; // Get Current Scroll Value

    if (currentScroll > 0 && lastScroll <= currentScroll) {
      lastScroll = currentScroll;
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      navbar.classList.remove("z-index-999999");
    } else {
      lastScroll = currentScroll;
      navbar.classList.add("sticky");
      navbar.classList.add("z-index-999999");
    }

    if (currentScroll < 100) {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      navbar.classList.remove("z-index-999999");
    }

  };
}

scrollDetect();
```

```css
.main-navbar{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color:white;
  top: 6.3%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.5rem;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 4px rgb(110, 109, 109);
}

/*Code for Sticky*/
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  animation: faceInEffect 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation: faceInEffect 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes faceInEffect {
  from {

    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {

    opacity: 1;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="dropdown-item-1">
        <a href="">Men</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>



<div class="contentforscroll>

 src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/f_auto/dpr_1.0,cs_srgb/w_906,c_limit/83f15213-514a-4963-a765-74c379b89a34/nike-just-do-it.png"
        alt="" style="width: 1300px;">
<img  src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/f_auto/dpr_1.0,cs_srgb/w_906,c_limit/83f15213-514a-4963-a765-74c379b89a34/nike-just-do-it.png"
        alt="" style="width: 1300px;">></img>
</div>
```

Comment: I would change the top value from `-100%` to a pixel value (or 4.5rem the navbar height).

Also insinde the transition you have to say what you want to transition like `transition: height 0.2s ease-in;`

And put the same transition on the main-navbar so the transition works both ways.